# What is Extremal Length?

Tags: conformal-geometry, quasiconformal-maps

The question is as the title asks.
My background is in computer science, and recently I'm trying to read a paper that involves using extremal length to prove certain properties of planar graphs.

I have a little bit of difficulty understanding the problem conceptually, as far as I understand it's a measure of a upper bound to cross some shape, there is a few examples with rectangles and annuli on wikipedia, but it's a bit hard to understand what its doing and what its for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Intuition

If we think of curves as roads, then the extremal length of a family of curves describes how long it takes for a lot of people to drive along them from end to end, accounting for traffic in congested areas (where many roads merge). If set $A$ is a suburb and $B$ is a business area of a city, then the extremal length of all roads connecting $A$ to $B$ describes how long the average commute time is.

#### Invariance

The  main property of extremal length is its conformal invariance: if 
$\Gamma$ is some family of curves, and $f$ is a conformal map of a domain that contains all curves in $\Gamma$, then the family of images $\{f\circ  \gamma : \gamma\in\Gamma\}$ has the same conformal length as $\Gamma$ itself.

Moreover, this invariance is robust in the sense that if $f$ is only quasiconformal (has a controlled deviation from conformality), then the extremal length of the image is distorted only by a certain multiplicative amount. One might say it's quasi-invariant under quasiconformal maps.

So, on one hand the extremal length is a geometric concept; on another, it is related to the analytic properties of maps such as Cauchy-Riemann or Beltrami equations. This makes it a useful tool for deriving geometric conclusions from analytic assumptions, or vice versa.

#### Reference

The classical book [Lectures on Quasiconformal Mappings](https://books.google.com/books?id=DKuTAwAAQBAJ) by Ahlfors has both an accessible introduction to extremal length, and its applications such as a sharp Hölder continuity estimate for quasiconformal maps of the unit disk.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, so the extremal length is similar to water flowing through a pipe or current in a wire.